# What is this in my haxeflixel project.xml file?

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

i'm very new to haxeflixel, and i've been playing around with it for a while until i took a look at the project.xml file. i saw this line with some links on it:

```
project xmlns="http://lime.software/project/1.0.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://lime.software/project/1.0.2 http://lime.software/xsd/project-1.0.2.xsd"
```

can someone explain to me what this is? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

These are xml metadata defining the namespaces (ns) used in project.xml :

- by default lime's namespace for non prefixed nodes
- then xsi's namespace which is made available as prefix for nodes not using the default namespace
- next, the `xsi` namespace is used to indicate the location of the schema, which defines what the xml should or can contain to be valid project file, you can go to it's location to see : http://lime.software/xsd/project-1.0.2.xsd

Have fun with haxeflixel :)